# How to run a Python script from IDLE command line?

Tags: python, python-idle

In a bash shell, I can use 'bash ' or 'source ' to invoke a script by hand. Can I do the similar thing in the Python IDLE's interactive shell? I know I can go to File >> Open Module, then run it in a separate window, but that's troublesome.

Answer (score 4):

One method I have found is `execfile`.  It has the signature `execfile(<filename>,<globals>,<locals>)` and runs the file in the same thread as the current IDLE Session.  **This method is Python 2 specific**

The method the OP is asking for (in a different thread/window) would be to use `subprocess` to run in a different thread/window.

```
import subprocess

#any of these will run the file.  Pick the one that best suits you.

subprocess.call(['python','filename.py'])
subprocess.check_call(['python','filename.py'])
subprocess.Popen(['python','filename.py'])
```

These essentially do what [nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399444/how-to-run-a-python-script-from-idle-command-line#answer-15399457)'s answer does, but using `subprocess` to execute it in a different thread.

Comment: execfile() only works in Python 2.x. It's been removed in Python 3: http://python3porting.com/differences.html, where 'exec(open(thefile).read())' can be used, which returns the output back to the IDLE interactive shell, but I haven't figured out a way to pass the command line arguments. subprocess would work but it doesn't return the outputs, and requires more trouble to get it (though probably do-able). This is nothing compared to the "." operator in bash to execute a script. Too bad.

Comment: @HaiXinTie Thanks for noting that.  I've updated the answer to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 1):

If what you meant is executing in the Python IDLE's interactive shell instead of command prompt or command line, then I usually use this approach:

`python  -m idlelib.idle -r "C:/dir1/dir2/Your script.py"`

It works well with me. Tested on my Windows 10, python 3.7.3.

Please ensure that you have added your desired python version on your environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run a Python script from the commandline:

```
python <script.py>
```

Comment: I think the asker is looking for a way to do it inside the interactive shell, not just command line