# Run python script from shell and keeping defined modules/data

Tags: python, shell, module, terminal

I am new to Python and I am wondering how can I keep the modules and data from a script I run from the Python shell?

For example: I have the script helloworld.py and it contains:

```
import numpy as donkey
a = 55
```

Then I want to run that script from my Python shell:

```
execfile('helloworld.py')
```

However, if I then try to call for 'a' or 'donkey', they are not found.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you running it with `execfile`?

Comment: is there any other function i can use? My script is huge, thats why i want to run everything in the beginning and then be able to access my defined functions/modules etc..

Comment: Why not just `import` it?

Comment: ok seems good, how should i execute the imported script?

Comment: What do you mean? All of the code at the top level of the script (unless guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__':`) will be executed on import.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because importing does not copy over the global variables from parent file to child file. It DOES do so in the reverse.

Comment: Well there is a main(), at more bottom of the script, which right not run automatically after import..

Comment: If file1 has a global variable `a`, it does not get copied into the scope of file2 when file2 is imported. However, if file2 says "from file1 import *", it will get incorporated into the globals. Why the downvote?

Comment: *"it does not get copied into the scope of file2 when file2 is imported"* - and how is that relevant? The OP appears to be trying to get the definitions from a script into an interpreter session, not vice versa. Please re-read the example provided.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using IDLE.  IDLE is not a shell in Unix sense. So there is not a direct equivalent of the bash shell `. ~/.bash_profile`.

Instead I edit the file and then use  F5 Run Module. All my variables, functions, and classes get loaded. I can use the interpretive shell to manipulate. However, if I run another module, I reset the environment, losing the first module's definitions.

The execfile() approach is limited to Python 2 as noted here:
[How to run a Python script from IDLE command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399444/how-to-run-a-python-script-from-idle-command-line)